# Web scraping using R to get price report

Tags: r, web-scraping

I need to get the "price report" from https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/reports/report_menu_web.aspx for each day of the months of February - March 2020. I tried opening these data from the website by plugging in the date filter of the website. Each of them open as a .aspx but I'm unable to figure out why there are no differences in their urls.
I need to write a code in R to save each of these as a separate excel sheet.
I truly appreciate any help in this regard.

Comment: When you select an option on the website you are sending a POST request to the server which updates your session information. This information is used on the sever to determine which page to deliver the next time the same url is requested. Although it might be possible to reverse-engineer the POST requests in R, this is a situation where using a browser with automation via RSelenium is going to be easier.

Comment: I am unable to put the code together.

Comment: Sorry to hear that Debika. Would you like to edit your question show us what you have so far?

Comment: To be honest I didn't really write anything. I looked up quite a few tutorials but none of them deal with this kind of a .aspx website so I really cannot find any reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an approach that can be considered :

```
library(RDCOMClient)
url <- "https://fcainfoweb.nic.in/reports/report_menu_web.aspx"
IEApp <- COMCreate("InternetExplorer.Application")
IEApp[['Visible']] <- TRUE
IEApp$Navigate(url)
Sys.sleep(5)
doc <- IEApp$Document()

clickEvent <- doc$createEvent("MouseEvent")
clickEvent$initEvent("click", TRUE, FALSE)

web_Obj <- doc$querySelector('#ctl00_MainContent_Rbl_Rpt_type > tbody > tr:nth-child(1) > td > label')
web_Obj$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)
Sys.sleep(2)

web_Obj_Select <- doc$querySelector('#ctl00_MainContent_Ddl_Rpt_Option0')
web_Obj_Select[["Value"]] <- "Daily Prices"
web_Obj_Select$FireEvent("onchange")
Sys.sleep(2)

web_Obj_Date <- doc$querySelector('#ctl00_MainContent_Txt_FrmDate')
web_Obj_Date[["Value"]] <- "14/09/2022"
Sys.sleep(2)

web_Obj_Get_Data <- doc$querySelector('#ctl00_MainContent_btn_getdata1')
web_Obj_Get_Data$dispatchEvent(clickEvent)

Sys.sleep(120)

html_Content <- doc$documentElement()$innerHtml()
read_html(html_Content) %>% html_table()

[[1]]
# A tibble: 276 x 6,177
   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17   X18   X19   X20   X21   X22   X23   X24  
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 ""    NA    NA    NA    NA     NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 2 "Dep~ Depa~ Date~ Dail~ Unit~ "Cen~ Cent~ Rice  Wheat Atta~ Gram~ Tur/~ Urad~ Moon~ Maso~ Sugar Milk~ Grou~ Must~ Vana~ Soya~ Sunf~ Palm~ Gur  
 3 "Dep~ Date~ Dail~ Unit~ NA     NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 4 "Dat~ Dail~ Unit~ NA    NA     NA   NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
 5 "Cen~ Cent~ Rice  Wheat Atta~ "Gra~ Tur/~ Urad~ Moon~ Maso~ Sugar Milk~ Grou~ Must~ Vana~ Soya~ Sunf~ Palm~ Gur   Tea ~ Salt~ Pota~ Onion Toma~
 6 "Cen~ Rice  Wheat Atta~ Gram~ "Tur~ Urad~ Moon~ Maso~ Sugar Milk~ Grou~ Must~ Vana~ Soya~ Sunf~ Palm~ Gur   Tea ~ Salt~ Pota~ Onion Toma~ NA   
 7 "Ave~ 38.15 31.15 36.07 74.28 "111~ 108.~ 103.~ 97.12 42.57 53.68 187.~ 170.4 152.~ 152.~ 173.~ 126.~ 51.41 278.~ 20.74 28.36 26.23 41.81 NA   
 8 "Max~ 61    45    65    120   "142" 175   145   134   55    80    250   255   227   218   238   188   120   547   30    53    60    73    NA   
 9 "Min~ 22    18    24    57    "75"  73    80    77    36    32    155   140   103   125   141   98    35    123   8     13    12    17    NA   
10 "Mod~ 40    25    35    70    "110" 100   97.5  90    40    48    186.~ 162   160   150   190   137   46    240   25    25    28    40    NA   
# ... with 266 more rows, and 6,153 more variables: X25 <chr>, X26 <chr>, X27 <chr>, X28 <chr>, X29 <chr>, X30 <chr>, X31 <dbl>, X32 <dbl>,
#   X33 <dbl>, X34 <dbl>, X35 <dbl>, X36 <dbl>, X37 <dbl>, X38 <dbl>, X39 <dbl>, X40 <dbl>, X41 <dbl>, X42 <dbl>, X43 <dbl>, X44 <dbl>,
#   X45 <dbl>, X46 <dbl>, X47 <dbl>, X48 <chr>, X49 <dbl>, X50 <dbl>, X51 <dbl>, X52 <dbl>, X53 <chr>, X54 <int>, X55 <int>, X56 <int>,
#   X57 <int>, X58 <int>, X59 <int>, X60 <int>, X61 <int>, X62 <int>, X63 <int>, X64 <int>, X65 <int>, X66 <int>, X67 <int>, X68 <int>,
#   X69 <int>, X70 <int>, X71 <chr>, X72 <int>, X73 <int>, X74 <int>, X75 <int>, X76 <chr>, X77 <int>, X78 <int>, X79 <int>, X80 <int>,
#   X81 <int>, X82 <int>, X83 <int>, X84 <int>, X85 <int>, X86 <int>, X87 <int>, X88 <int>, X89 <int>, X90 <int>, X91 <int>, X92 <int>,
#   X93 <int>, X94 <chr>, X95 <int>, X96 <int>, X97 <int>, X98 <int>, X99 <chr>, X100 <int>, X101 <dbl>, X102 <int>, X103 <int>, X104 <int>, ...
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names

[[2]]
# A tibble: 274 x 6,165
   X1    X2    X3    X4    X5    X6    X7    X8    X9    X10   X11   X12   X13   X14   X15   X16   X17   X18   X19   X20   X21   X22   X23   X24  
   <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
 1 "Dep~ "Dat~ "Dai~ "Uni~  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA   
 2 "Dat~ "Dai~ "Uni~  NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   NA   
 3 "Cen~ "Cen~ "Ric~ "Whe~ "Att~ "Gra~ "Tur~ "Ura~ "Moo~ "Mas~ "Sug~ "Mil~ "Gro~ "Mus~ "Van~ "Soy~ "Sun~ "Pal~ "Gur" "Tea~ "Sal~ "Pot~ "Oni~ Toma~
 4 "Cen~ "Ric~ "Whe~ "Att~ "Gra~ "Tur~ "Ura~ "Moo~ "Mas~ "Sug~ "Mil~ "Gro~ "Mus~ "Van~ "Soy~ "Sun~ "Pal~ "Gur" "Tea~ "Sal~ "Pot~ "Oni~ "Tom~ NA   
 5 "Ave~ "38.~ "31.~ "36.~ "74.~ "111~ "108~ "103~ "97.~ "42.~ "53.~ "187~ "170~ "152~ "152~ "173~ "126~ "51.~ "278~ "20.~ "28.~ "26.~ "41.~ NA   
 6 "Max~ "61"  "45"  "65"  "120" "142" "175" "145" "134" "55"  "80"  "250" "255" "227" "218" "238" "188" "120" "547" "30"  "53"  "60"  "73"  NA   
 7 "Min~ "22"  "18"  "24"  "57"  "75"  "73"  "80"  "77"  "36"  "32"  "155" "140" "103" "125" "141" "98"  "35"  "123" "8"   "13"  "12"  "17"  NA   
 8 "Mod~ "40"  "25"  "35"  "70"  "110" "100" "97.~ "90"  "40"  "48"  "186~ "162" "160" "150" "190" "137" "46"  "240" "25"  "25"  "28"  "40"  NA   
 9 "NOR~ ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    ""    NA   
10 "CHA~ "38"  "24"  "28"  "78"  "113" "111" "112" "90"  "42"  "57"  "177" "177" "175" "168" "170" "145" "48"  "229" "23"  "26"  "28"  "48"  NA   
# ... with 264 more rows, and 6,141 more variables: X25 <chr>, X26 <dbl>, X27 <dbl>, X28 <dbl>, X29 <dbl>, X30 <dbl>, X31 <dbl>, X32 <dbl>,
#   X33 <dbl>, X34 <dbl>, X35 <dbl>, X36 <dbl>, X37 <dbl>, X38 <dbl>, X39 <dbl>, X40 <dbl>, X41 <dbl>, X42 <dbl>, X43 <dbl>, X44 <dbl>,
#   X45 <dbl>, X46 <dbl>, X47 <dbl>, X48 <chr>, X49 <int>, X50 <int>, X51 <int>, X52 <int>, X53 <int>, X54 <int>, X55 <int>, X56 <int>,
#   X57 <int>, X58 <int>, X59 <int>, X60 <int>, X61 <int>, X62 <int>, X63 <int>, X64 <int>, X65 <int>, X66 <int>, X67 <int>, X68 <int>,
#   X69 <int>, X70 <int>, X71 <chr>, X72 <int>, X73 <int>, X74 <int>, X75 <int>, X76 <int>, X77 <int>, X78 <int>, X79 <int>, X80 <int>,
#   X81 <int>, X82 <int>, X83 <int>, X84 <int>, X85 <int>, X86 <int>, X87 <int>, X88 <int>, X89 <int>, X90 <int>, X91 <int>, X92 <int>,
#   X93 <int>, X94 <chr>, X95 <int>, X96 <int>, X97 <int>, X98 <int>, X99 <int>, X100 <int>, X101 <dbl>, X102 <int>, X103 <int>, X104 <int>, ...
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names

[[3]]
# A tibble: 1 x 3
  X1               X2                                           X3           
  <chr>            <chr>                                        <chr>        
1 Date  14/09/2022 Daily Retail Prices Of Essential Commodities Unit: (?/Kg.)

[[4]]
# A tibble: 267 x 23
   Centre  Rice  Wheat Atta ~1 Gram ~2 Tur/A~3 Urad ~4 Moong~5 Masoo~6 Sugar Milk ~7 Groun~8 Musta~9 Vanas~* Soya ~* Sunfl~* Palm ~* Gur   Tea L~*
   <chr>   <chr> <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr> <chr>  
 1 Averag~ "38.~ "31.~ "36.07" "74.28" "111.5~ "108.2~ "103.0~ "97.12" "42.~ "53.68" "187.7~ "170.4" "152.1~ "152.8~ "173.3~ "126.5~ "51.~ "278.4~
 2 Maximu~ "61"  "45"  "65"    "120"   "142"   "175"   "145"   "134"   "55"  "80"    "250"   "255"   "227"   "218"   "238"   "188"   "120" "547"  
 3 Minimu~ "22"  "18"  "24"    "57"    "75"    "73"    "80"    "77"    "36"  "32"    "155"   "140"   "103"   "125"   "141"   "98"    "35"  "123"  
 4 Modal ~ "40"  "25"  "35"    "70"    "110"   "100"   "97.5"  "90"    "40"  "48"    "186.6~ "162"   "160"   "150"   "190"   "137"   "46"  "240"  
 5 NORTH ~ ""    ""    ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""    ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""      ""    ""     
 6 CHANDI~ "38"  "24"  "28"    "78"    "113"   "111"   "112"   "90"    "42"  "57"    "177"   "177"   "175"   "168"   "170"   "145"   "48"  "229"  
 7 DELHI   "32"  "25"  "30"    "72"    "115"   "127"   "100"   "93"    "41"  "52"    "203"   "179"   "154"   "154"   "207"   "126"   "58"  "224"  
 8 HISAR   "30"  "24"  "27"    "60"    "105"   "90"    "90"    "90"    "40"  "56"    "185"   "145"   "135"   "145"   "185"   "132"   "42"  "240"  
 9 KARNAL  "37"  "26"  "32"    "76"    "105"   "106"   "106"   "104"   "42"  "62"    "176"   "171"   "156"   "161"   "165"   "140"   "45"  "278"  
10 PANCHK~ "29"  "24"  "29"    "66"    "108"   "92"    "96"    "85"    "43"  "55"    "213"   "180"   "185"   "164"   "197"   "131"   "45"  "255"  
# ... with 257 more rows, 4 more variables: `Salt Pack (Iodised)` <chr>, Potato <chr>, Onion <chr>, Tomato <chr>, and abbreviated variable names
#   1: `Atta (Wheat)`, 2: `Gram Dal`, 3: `Tur/Arhar Dal`, 4: `Urad Dal`, 5: `Moong Dal`, 6: `Masoor Dal`, 7: `Milk @`,
#   8: `Groundnut Oil (Packed)`, 9: `Mustard Oil (Packed)`, *: `Vanaspati (Packed)`, *: `Soya Oil (Packed)`, *: `Sunflower Oil (Packed)`,
#   *: `Palm Oil (Packed)`, *: `Tea Loose`
# i Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows, and `colnames()` to see all variable names

[[5]]
# A tibble: 2 x 4
  X1                                               X2                                                                                  X3    X4   
  <chr>                                            <chr>                                                                               <chr> <lgl>
1 Source:-  State civil supplies Dept.             Note:- All India Average Prices of Oils are on Weightage (Consumption) basis w.e.f~ NR -~ NA   
2 Developed by:-  National Informatics Centre(NIC) Developed by:-  National Informatics Centre(NIC)                                    NA    NA
```